# How do I return the intersecting value from 2 partial match lookups? Index/Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables in an excel worksheet. I'm trying to gather product info from data on another table in the same workbook. The first table is the product data feed I'm building with the product part numbers. Those part numbers include the variables of the product (in this case the length and the width). On the other sheet, I have partial part numbers in the header column and the rough dimensions in the header row. The intersection gives the final dimensions which is the data I'm trying to gather on sheet 1. I've been trying to use and Index/Match formula to solve the problem, but since there are only partial part numbers on the 2nd sheet the lookup is inconclusive. I know the lookup value supports wildcards, but it seems I would need some sort of wildcard search within the lookup array instead.

Example product names on sheet 1 column A "EXP81285-150-11 x 14-Flat"

Example of product names on sheet 2 column A "EXP81285-150"
Example of rough dimensions on sheet 2 row 1 "11 x 14"

Here is what I have so far:

```
=INDEX('sheet 2'!$A$1:$L$87,MATCH($A3,'sheet 2'!$A:$A,0),MATCH($A3,'sheet 2'!$1:$1,0))
```

Sheet 1
[image: http://i.imgur.com/WIA4ioM.png]

Sheet 2
[image: http://i.imgur.com/6vUXrv4.png]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried to add images of the excel files but I dont have enough reputation points yet

Comment: Upload to a site like imugr and provide link in your original post.

Comment: Got it, added image links from imgur. Thanks Scott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming its always like `string1-string2-unused` and `string2` and `unused` doesn't contain "-" you can get the first string with:

```
*updated due to misunderstanding*
=MID(A3,4,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","|",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-",""))-1))-4)
```

While the `string2` one is a hell of a formula:

```
=MID(A3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","|",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-",""))-1))+1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","|",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-",""))))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-","|",LEN(A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A3,"-",""))-1))-1)
```

Asuming the last part is allways in `Q3` then:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-"&$Q3,""),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-","|",LEN($A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-",""))-1))+1,99)
```

You may also use an arrayformula for the second part like:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-"&$Q3,""),LARGE((MID($A3,ROW($1:$99),1)="-")*ROW($1:$99),2)+1,99)
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

(the second formula may work faster)
You could use array formulas in a reverse `Match` however... having lots of entrys even one formula will slow down the calculation by ~2-5 seconds.

You better use VBA like:
(in Module)

```
Public Function MATCH2(str As String, rng As Range) As Long
  Dim i As Long, var1 As Variant
  i = 0
  For Each var1 In rng
    i = i + 1
    If InStr(str, var1.Value) Then MATCH2 = i: Exit Function
  Next
End Function
```

And then use your formula as followed:

```
=INDEX('sheet 2'!$A$1:$L$87,MATCH2($A3,'sheet 2'!$A:$A,0),MATCH2($A3,'sheet 2'!$1:$1,0))
```

**EDIT** 2015-11-19

OK... some small problems:

1. some sizes doesnt exist (like `6 x 9`)
2. size `7 x 12` was bugged (a space at the end > fixed it)
3. the function needs to be in a `module` (also fixed that)
4. also some items doesn't exist like `600823-002`
5. a misunderstanding regarding the formulas (doesn't matter at the VBA-version) > all asumed the `A:A`-searchstring starts at the 1st character (but it is the 4th, no `EXP`)

Also there will be an error at each "header" (the ones without the `* x *` but that should be ok)

[You can download the updated workbook here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_752Ga6Yb7uLVlyUDBJdi0zZkU/view?usp=sharing)
If you still have questions, just ask :)

Comment: wow, yeah that second formula is crazy. would those replace the 2 match functions within the index function?

Comment: not too worried about processing time as we will most likely only use this once. I'm just trying to avoid a few days worth of data entry work.

Comment: no...they would only replace the `$A3` in your match as the search string... it would end up with `=INDEX('sheet 2'!$A$1:$L$87,MATCH(LEFT($A3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-","|",LEN($A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-",""))-1))-1),'sheet 2'!$A:$A,0),MATCH(MID($A3,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-","|",LEN($A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-",""))-1))+1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-","|",LEN($A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-",""))))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-","|",LEN($A3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($A3,"-",""))-1))-1),'sheet 2'!$1:$1,0))`

Comment: I tried the vbscript method but it's only returning #VALUE!

Comment: hmm.... works as it should be... can't get any errors.... but a question: are you sure `sheet 2` has a space?

Comment: I tried renaming the sheet to with and without the space just to test, still not working for me. Using Excel for Mac shouldn't be an issue should it? It has a VB editor that seems to working

Comment: No...they work the same way... but try to only use the `=MATCH2($A3,'sheet 2'!A:A)` did you still get `#VALUE`?

Comment: that successfully gave me a value, i think we're close.

Comment: asuming `=MATCH2($A3,'sheet 2'!$1:$1,0)` also gives a value, `=INDEX('sheet 2'!$A$1:$L$87,MATCH2($A3,'sheet 2'!$A:$A,0),MATCH2($A3,'sheet 2'!$1:$1,0))` should work...it may be possible that the matches are outside of your range `'sheet 2'!$A$1:$L$87`... please recheck if the single values are correct AND inside `A1:L87` (first formula should be between 1 and 87, second between 1 and 12)

Comment: Please try this formula with the function: `=INDEX('sheet 2'!$A:$AA,MATCH2($A3,'sheet 2'!$A:$A,0),MATCH2($A3,'sheet 2'!$1:$1,0))`

Comment: I double-checked and the column and row counts are correct, data goes to the 87th row, and columns go to K now (i removed one column of extraneous data that might have caused complications). The cells in sheet 2 are also formula-generated, but that shouldn't affect this formula should it, considering it should only return the generated values? Scott mentioned that spaces could cause complications, there are spaces before and after the " X " in those generated cells. Anyway i can link you the files? Thanks for all the time and effort, I really appreciate it.

Comment: That would help a lot... right now we cant understand why its not working... (asuming there is no critical data inside / buissness secrets you can share them and we check whats the problem)

Comment: @BrianHassett i've edited my answer and also provided a link for you :)

Comment: Phenomenal! Thank you so much Dirk, that was a huge help for us! I have another spreadsheet I will probably have to use the same formula on now too. I'd send you cookies if I could.

Comment: Sorry, no payment allowed :D but feel free to come back when ever you are in need of help

Answer (score 0):

Here is one using vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2,10)-1),Sheet2!A:L,MATCH(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2,10)+1,(FIND("-",A2,15))-(FIND("-",A2,10)+1)),Sheet2!A1:L1,0),FALSE)
```

But I agree with Dirk, This could be done faster and probably more accurate with vba.

Edit, I realized that my dictating of 10 and 15 in the formula would not work, I have fixed it, but it is based on the part number has 1 and only 1 "-" in the part name.  Warning it is quite long.

```
=VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2,1)+1)-1),Sheet2!A:L,MATCH(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2,1)+1)+1,(FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2,1)+1))+1))-(FIND("-",A2,FIND("-",A2,1)+1)+1)),Sheet2!A1:L1,0),FALSE)
```

Comment: `FIND("-",A2,10)` it thats working for all cases, it would be a huge time-saver :)

Comment: @DirkReichel Yeah the 10 is an assumption that the first part it fairly uniform. If it is not then your bible length code would be best.

Comment: however... having always the last part in column `Q` gives the option to simply replace `"-"&$Q3` with `""` also would save a lot of time... i'll do some tests :D

Comment: just tried it, although i had to remove the space in "sheet 2" to avoid editing the formula. unfortunately, even though the formula doesn't error, it's still returning #N/A for all fields i copy down the formula too in that column

Comment: @BrianHassett My Guess is that your data has spaces and or other hidden characters that are keeping the formulas and code from finding the exact match.  This goes for both Dirk's answer and mine.

Comment: Not sure, there are spaces before and after the " X " in the dimensions, but other than that, there spaces. Those cells on sheet 2 are formula-generated as well.